# How to get the whole HTML value from Dijit Editor

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget, dijit.form, ibm-content-navigator

Hello Experts I need help

I'm using dojo `Dijit Editor` "rich text editor" field in my widget, on page load I fetch HTML text from database and I set the rich text editor with the HTML normally, Then user can edit the displayed text and on page close I have to set the field in database with the source HTML of the edited text by user
the problem is when I do the following "`myDB_txt=myEditor.getValue()`;" `getValue()` doesn't return the complete HTML code it removes HTML tag and header tag and body tag which causes me troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `myEditorWidget.get("Value")` where myEditorWidget refer to your `dijit/Editor` indtance

To wrap this result you can define a function that return result wraped by html tags

```
wrapResult(myEditor.get("value")));

function wrapResult(html) {

  return "<html> <head></head> <body>"+html+"</body></html>";

}
```

Here is a Sample with wraped result [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/8ke2q71r/4/) .

Otherwise If you want to get the whole HTML enclosing the content dijit ,

you will get access to it's `Iframe` ( that has the `id="editor_iframe"`)
and then get get the html `document` of this last like bellow (here  you should import `dojo/query` package)

```
query("#editor_iframe")[0].contentDocument.documentElement.outerHTML
```

Here is another [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/8ke2q71r/5/) .

Comment: I know that get("Value") will return me the value but I need the value to be in HTML format

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following to retrieve the value from your `dijit/Editor` instance.

```
var content = myEditor.attr("value");
var openTags = '<html><head></head><body>';
var closeTags = '</body></html>';
var html = openTags + content + closeTags; // use this
```

or

```
var htmlWrapper = function(content){
    return '<html><head></head><body>' + content + '</body></html>';
}; 
var html = htmlWrapper(myEditor.attr("value"));
```

Comment: it works as get("value"); 
i found the result something like that
<div class="alignCenter smallSizeFont bold" style="width: 25%; float: left;">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse">
   <tbody><tr>
    <td>Manager</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Investors</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody></table>
 </div>

Comment: I need it to be full HTML Code
Like that
<html>
<header></header>
<body>
<div class="alignCenter smallSizeFont bold" style="width: 25%; float: left;"> <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding: 0px; border-collapse: collapse"> <tbody><tr> <td>Manager</td> </tr> <tr> <td>Investors</td> </tr> </tbody></table> </div> 
</body
</html>

Comment: @user1814595 in this case you need to concatenate the strings yourself. I made an edit to my answer with a possible solution. Let me know if it works for you. Thanks.

Comment: @GibboK , Your welcome :) , it's always a pleasure for me .